# Are dynamic libraries loaded on startup or only when required by executable

Tags: linux, linker, dynamic-linking, dynamic-library, dynamic-loading

Take a C application running on Linux for example which is dynamically linked with a required shared library.

I know that the `.so` file should be found in the paths defined in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` .

Does the dynamic linker load this library on startup of the application regardless? Or can it load it only when a function call from that library is required? If the latter, how would it actually know which function belongs to which library?

Comment: Good source of information about dynamic linker is its manual page `man ld-linux`. In particular you may be interested in LD_BIND_NOW environment variable.

Comment: @gudok The `LD_BIND_NOW` is not related to library loading - it controls whether addresses of library function are resolved at startup or delayed until first call.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux libraries are loaded at program startup. Some systems (e.g. Windows or Solaris) support the *lazy loading* feature which delays library load until one of its functions is called (in this case the static linker will embed information which function belongs to which library into the executable).

Lazy loading can be emulated on Linux using tools like [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so).